# Is it halal to upload women mehndi/henna designs app

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sin, women

Asslam-o-Alaikum. I'm making an app which contains henna/mehndi designs for women. The images just contains the mehndi designs on arms and foot. This app is specifically and only for women. I'm making a starting screen to confirm that the user is only a woman. So can you please guide me if it is good to upload an app like this. And please tell me if someone cheats like a man confirms gender as a woman then will I be sinful for this Or a woman shows the images to a man. Please guide me. JazakAllah

Answer (score -1):

Yeah absolutely halal there's nothing haram In posting mehendi henna designs